# How to serialize/deserialize std::chrono::zoned_time?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, c++-chrono, c++23

The [`std::chrono::zoned_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time) is not a POD type (since it's not a [*trivial*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) type) and so it cannot be written/read to/from a file as a sequence of raw data. It has a time point member (`std::chrono::time_point`). It also has a pointer member that points at a [`std::chrono::time_zone`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone) object.

The problem is that the pointer member cannot be serialized/deserialized. But I want to store and retrieve the time zone of the `zoned_time` objects as well (and not just the time point). I guess one approach could be to get the name of the `std::chrono::time_zone` using [`std::chrono::time_zone::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone/name) and save that string_view and its size in the file.

I need to somehow fetch the member objects and serialize them. But how?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>


std::ofstream& operator<<( std::ofstream& ofs, const std::chrono::zoned_seconds& time )
{
    // What should go here?
    return ofs;
}

std::ifstream& operator>>( std::ifstream& ifs, std::chrono::zoned_seconds& time )
{
    // What should go here?
    return ifs;
}
```

Comment: What are you looking for that `std::chrono::zoned_time zt; std::cout << zt;` doesn't give you?

Comment: @Galik I believe the OP is missing the oposite operation (file I/O equivalent to `std::chrono::zoned_time zt1; std::cin >> zt1;`).

Comment: You can serialize to and from a string using chrono using [std::chrono::from_stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_stream) or [Create std::chrono::time_point from string `std::chrono::parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183145/create-stdchronotime-point-from-string)

Comment: @Galik I don't want to store an 8 byte integer as the size in the file and then store the characters. That's too many bytes being stored. The thing I'm trying to do is to store the object representation of the zoned_time object in the file if possible.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes. Also I want to be able to modify these objects stored in the file. I'm trying to implement a simple data base from scratch. This is why I need to store the local time as well.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/locate_zone will be useful when reading.  How you format the string is your choice: have you ever written serialization/deserialization before?  There are lots of pitfalls.

Comment: @digito_evo: "*The thing I'm trying to do is to store the object representation of the zoned_time object in the file if possible.*" You can't. As you discovered, the object representation includes a pointer, and that pointer's value can be different from execution to execution. You are going to have to serialize it as something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::chrono::zoned_seconds` is a very simple data structure under the hood:  `{std::chrono::time_zone const*, std::chrono::sys_seconds}`.

And each of these data members are both easily retrievable from an existing `zoned_seconds`, and a `zoned_seconds` is constructible from these two pieces of information.

So you can reduce your problem to two parts:

1. Serialize/deserialize a `std::chrono::time_zone const*`.
2. Serialize/deserialize a `std::chrono::sys_seconds`.

Also, big picture, I strongly recommend that you not use `operator<<` / `operator>>` for the names of these functions.  This will lead you to inconvenient ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) issues.  I recommend you choose other names that are put into your own namespace.  I'll arbitrarily choose these names to refer to these functions, but any descriptive names will do:

```
std::ostream&
put(std::ostream& os, std::chrono::zoned_seconds const& time);

std::istream&
get(std::istream& is, std::chrono::zoned_seconds& time);
```

Also note that I chose to use the more generic `ostream` and `istream` as opposed to the file versions `ofstream` and `ifstream`.  It is going to be the same coding either way.  And with the more generic versions you can easily test with `std::stringstream`.

So something like:

```
std::ostream&
put(std::ostream& os, std::chrono::zoned_seconds const& time)
{
    auto tz = time.get_time_zone();
    auto tp = time.get_sys_time();
    put(os, tz);
    put(os, tp);
    return os;
}

std::istream&
get(std::istream& is, std::chrono::zoned_seconds& time)
{
    auto tz = get_time_zone(is);
    auto tp = get_sys_seconds(is);
    time = std::chrono::zoned_seconds{tz, tp};
    return is;
}
```

The `put` function extracts the `time_zone const*` and the `sys_time`, at the precision of `seconds`, so `sys_seconds`, and then calls functions to serialize each of those pieces.

The `get` functions deserializes each piece, and then constructs a `zoned_seconds` with the two pieces of data and assigns that to `time`.

Now we have to look at how to implement these lower level functions:

`put` first:

```
std::ostream&
put(std::ostream& os, std::chrono::time_zone const* tz)
{
    return os << tz->name() << ' ';
}
```

This serializes the `time_zone const*` by extracting its name, and writing that out.  The `time_zone` names follow the rules laid down by the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  Valid characters are ASCII alphanumeric, along with a few other details.  You will need to follow the name with a delimiter that is not a valid character in an IANA time zone name. `' '` is a convenient delimiter.

```
std::chrono::time_zone const*
get_time_zone(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string tz_name;
    is >> tz_name;
    auto delimiter = static_cast<char>(is.get());
    return std::chrono::locate_zone(tz_name);
}
```

To deserialize the `time_zone const*`, just read in the name and the delimiter.  If you would like to error check that the delimiter is `' '`, or any other error checking, do that here.  Then the `string` can be turned into a `time_zone const*` by calling `locate_zone`.

*Note:* The above function is modified from my original answer.  It now reads `delimiter` with the *unformatted* function `is.get()`.  I previously read `delimiter` with the *formatted* stream operator.  Formatted stream functions skip over whitespace prior to beginning the parse.  It skipped over the character I was attempting to read into `delimiter`.

Next we need to serialize the `sys_seconds`.  Under the hood, `sys_seconds` just holds a `std::chrono::seconds`.  And a `std::chrono::seconds` holds a signed integral type that [has at least 35 bits](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn#def:signed_integer_type_of_at_least_35_bits) (so in practice an `int64_t`).

```
std::ostream&
put(std::ostream& os, std::chrono::sys_seconds tp)
{
    put(os, tp.time_since_epoch().count());
    return os;
}
```

One can extract the internal integer with `.time_since_epoch().count()`.  This first extracts the underlying `duration` of precision `seconds` from the `time_point` `sys_seconds`, and then extracts the integral value from the `seconds` `duration`.

Now serialize the integral type.  I won't go into details about that as that is covered in good detail elsewhere.  [For example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400522/576911). There is also a [boost library for this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) if desired.

```
std::chrono::sys_seconds
get_sys_seconds(std::istream& is)
{
    return std::chrono::sys_seconds{std::chrono::seconds{get_int64_t(is)}};
}
```

To deserialize the `sys_seconds`, first deserialize the `int64_t`, convert that to `seconds`, and then convert that to `sys_seconds`.

These simple steps will give you the most compact representation in your database possible.  The only way to get it more compact is to use a smaller integral type than `int64_t`, which of course is a design choice for you, not me.

If you choose to use `int32_t` (for example), your range will be limited to approximately the years 1902 to 2038.  And 2038 is coming up quickly.  So I don't recommend that.

If you choose `uint32_t` your range will be the years 1970 to about 2106.  This means you won't be able to store my birthday. ;-)

You might also choose to serizalize a signed 6 byte integer, saving 2 bytes per entry.  This would give you plenty of range (about +/- 4 million years).  I will leave it as an exercise how to modify [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400522/576911) to serialize 6 bytes instead of 4 or 8.

Comment: I tried your code and a bit of mine added to it. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/6G4q5s5fY) it is. Please take a look at it. The result that it shows is incorrect. Do you know why? I guess it's because I have mixed formatted input/output with unformatted I/O. Is it why?

Comment: My bad.  I had a bug in `get_time_zone`.  I've corrected the bug in my answer, and explained the bug as well.

Comment: Also, do you think all the put and get functions here should return `std::ostream` and `std::istream` respectively? I guess they should receive/return the value using their second parameter. This could make the API more consistent.

Comment: That's a stylistic decision with no firm "best way".  Returning the stream references allows you to chain together operations like this: `put(std::cout, zt2) << "more stuff\n";`. That may or may not be valuable for your use case.

Comment: But I should check the stream error state after each operation, shouldn't I?

Comment: Checking the error state is one approach.  Another is setting the exceptions flag so that an error in the stream throws an exception.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions